# Pdfbox throws multiple exception in linux but works fine on windows 7

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am currently working to get pdfbox working to extract all the images from pdfs. I am using pdfbox.1.8.7 jar file and below is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage;

public class PdfBoxExtractor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PdfBoxExtractor obj = new PdfBoxExtractor();
        try {
            obj.read_pdf();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("" + ex);
        }

    }

    void read_pdf() throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = PDDocument
                    .load("C:\\Testpdf\\pdfsample\\15802643.pdf");
//Linux path("/home/biadmin/freddy/15802643.pdf")
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("" + ex);
        }
        List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
        int i = 1;
        String name = null;

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) iter.next();
            PDResources resources = page.getResources();
            Map pageImages = resources.getImages();
            if (pageImages != null) {
                Iterator imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
                while (imageIter.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) imageIter.next();
                    PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage) pageImages.get(key);
                    image.write2file("C:\\processed\\pdf\\image" + i);
//Linux path (/home/biadmin/processed/image"+i)
                    i++;
                }
            }



        }

    }

}
```

I am porting the same code to a redhat 6.5 environment, changing the source/sink path in this code and trying to run it. But it gives numerous errors. I am currently clueless that why would same code fail in linux. 
JRE in both is Oracle - JRE 1.7
Please see the error I get in Linux.

```
Dec 7, 2014 4:52:44 AM org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument finalize
WARNING: Warning: You did not close a PDF Document
Dec 7, 2014 4:52:44 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap getRGBImage
SEVERE: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
Throwable occurred: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:352)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBuffer.seek(RandomAccessBuffer.java:110)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessFileOutputStream.write(RandomAccessFileOutputStream.java:116)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.filter.RunLengthDecodeFilter.decode(RunLengthDecodeFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.doDecode(COSStream.java:318)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.doDecode(COSStream.java:266)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.getUnfilteredStream(COSStream.java:192)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.createInputStream(PDStream.java:232)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.getByteArray(PDStream.java:510)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap.getRGBImage(PDPixelMap.java:255)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap.write2OutputStream(PDPixelMap.java:386)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDXObjectImage.write2file(PDXObjectImage.java:262)
    at com.vinayak.PdfBoxExtractor3.read_pdf(PdfBoxExtractor3.java:45)
    at com.vinayak.PdfBoxExtractor3.main(PdfBoxExtractor3.java:16)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vinayak.PdfBoxExtractor3.read_pdf(PdfBoxExtractor3.java:39)
    at com.vinayak.PdfBoxExtractor3.main(PdfBoxExtractor3.java:16)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you testing against the same PDF?

Comment: Yes, It the same pdf file. 
Infact in Test 2, I used a different pdf (not pdf's) on windows and linux and still linux gave the same issue.

Comment: Can you share the PDF? And is your Java running in headless mode?

Comment: I am not aware what is headless mode.

Comment: For headless mode see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html). As PDFBox uses awt classes in some contexts, it might be influenced by it. That been said, please share the PDF in question for analysis. Maybe there is something special to it.